# Open a link within a container nuxt-link

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a container element, that is wrapped in a `<nuxt-link>`. This content contains a range of data, but one of these will be to open a modal of info. At the moment, when I click the `<a>` tag to open the modal, it loads the link from the `<nuxt-link>`. When I go back, the modal is then open.

How can I make it so when I click the `<a>` tag, the link does not go to where the `<nuxt-link>` goes, and only opens the modal?

```
   <nuxt-link
      class="content-container-cta"
      :to="'/new-page/'"
      :title="'View the full details'"
   >

      <---- Some content ---->

      <a
         v-if="showModal" 
         @click="openModal"
         class="modal-link" 
      >
         Open Modal
      </a>

      <---- Some content ---->

   </nuxt-link>
```

Comment: Try `@click.stop="openModal"`

Comment: this didn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't do that since [nested links are illegal](http://w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2) and `nuxt-link` is just an `a` tag.
however, you can use a regular `div` instead of the `a` tag and use `@click.prevent` like

```html
<nuxt-link 
  class="content-container-cta" 
  :to="'/new-page/'" 
  :title="'View the full details'">
  <---- Some content ---->
    <div v-if="showModal" @click.prevent="openModal" class="modal-link">
      Open Modal
    </div>
    <---- Some content ---->
</nuxt-link>
```

also look at https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#event-modifiers

> check out this [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-almeida-ytpsy2?file=/src/App.vue) that contains a working example using an `a` tag and a `div` inside it.
> when you tap anywhere in the inner div (`chocolate` color block) it'll just log in the console but if you click on the `cyan` colored box it'll open a url in a new tab